# Activity finish() refresh the ListActiviyt

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, contextmenu, listactivity

i want to refresh/update afeter i select the "delete" ContextItem, it deletes but dont "refresh" the listview
see on code ListActivity:

```
public class ProjetoProTelefoneActivity extends ListActivity {
public final static String ID_EXTRA = "br.com.DaniloDeLuca.ProjetoProTelefone._ID";
Cursor modelo = null;
RestaurantAdapter adapter = null;
RestauranteHelper helper=null;
SharedPreferences prefs=null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    helper = new RestauranteHelper(this);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    initList();
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    helper.close();
}

//*********************************************************************************************************************************
// Long Press menu
//*********************************************************************************************************************************
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {        
        return;
    }
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return;
    }
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option_item,menu);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    View view = info.targetView;
    long id = info.id;

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.edit){
        Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
        return(true);
    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.remove){

        Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DeleteItemList.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
        return(true);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
//*********************************************************************************************************************************
// Fim Long Press menu
//*********************************************************************************************************************************
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view,
        int position,long id){
    Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);
}
//hook into menu button for activity 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option,menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
/// when menu button option selected 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add){
        startActivity(new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class));
        return(true);
    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.prefs){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
        return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener=
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                    String key) {
                if(key.equals("sort_order")){
                    initList();
                }

            }
};
private void initList(){
    if(modelo!=null){
        stopManagingCursor(modelo);
        modelo.close();
    }

    modelo =helper.getAll(prefs.getString("sort_order","nome DESC"));
    startManagingCursor(modelo);

    adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(modelo);       
    setListAdapter(adapter);         

}

class RestaurantAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    RestaurantAdapter(Cursor c) {
      super(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                         Cursor c) {
      RestaurantHolder holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();

      holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }


    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      RestaurantHolder holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);

      row.setTag(holder);

      return(row);
    }
  }

  static class RestaurantHolder {
    private TextView name=null;
    private TextView address=null;
    private ImageView icon=null;

    RestaurantHolder(View row) {
      name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
      address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
      icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor r,RestauranteHelper helper) {
      name.setText(helper.getNome(r));
      address.setText(helper.getEnd(r));


      if (helper.getTipo(r).equals("casa")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.casa_icon);
      }
      else if (helper.getTipo(r).equals("apartamento")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.apartamento_icon);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.comercio_ico);
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Now my DeleteItemList:

```
public class DeleteItemList extends Activity{
RestauranteHelper helper = null;
String restauranteId= null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    helper= new RestauranteHelper(this);


    restauranteId=getIntent().getStringExtra(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.ID_EXTRA);

    helper.delete(restauranteId);
    finish();
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();

}
```

}

RestauranteHelper.delete:

```
    public void delete(String id){
    String[] args = {id};

    getWritableDatabase().delete("restaurantes", "_ID =?", args);

}
```

idk if its clear what i want to do... i want to refresh the list, afeter selecting "Remove" option.

=D

Comment: Where is the definition for `RestauranteHelper.delete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the items in the list call the notifyDatasetChanged on your list adapter. That will do it.

Here is how the ListView will work.

After you initialize the list, set the items in the list adapter. 
Now call listview.setAdapter method to set the adapter.

Now when ever you make any changes in the items, change them on the list that you have passed to the adapter.

Then call the notofyDatasetChanged on your adapter.

That should work. If that is not working, then something else is wrong and try to debug each step of your code.

** In your case you are calling the delete on the database helper, but your cursor or adapter does not update when you change your stuff on the database. You need to remove that item from the cursor or query the database again and then pass it to the adapter.

Comment: i did that but dindt work, dont refresh the list after i click the "remove" contextmenuitem, if i click in some item (goes to edit) and back to main that it refreshs...

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. I did not look into your entire code, but that is how ListView works and I have been using it since a long time in my apps. I will edit my answer to explain the flow.

Comment: IM on ListActivity, i longpress one in a item then appears one ContextMenu(edit, remove), i choose "remove", when i choose this it has to delete(its working) and refresh the Llistactivity, but it dont refresh, the list is the same until i go to other layout/activity
sry but is hard for me explain it in english
"/

Comment: I edited my answer with comments at the end regarding delete in the database. You are deleting items from database. But that will not affect your cursor or adapter. So consider calling the query again or removing the item from cursor and then calling notifyDatasetChanged or consider changing the adapter to arrayAdapter if you find that you do not want to do all these manipulations on cursor.

Comment: I finish() the activity DeleteItemList it dont refresh the listView,
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/285744_304020273023375_23988020_n.jpg

if i choose the "Remover" on the third image, it deletes the item, but dont start a new list to show, appear the same thing

Comment: No worries about your english. It was clear enough what you wanted to say. It would have been nice if you had posted only the relevant code instead of your whole list activity. For example all that I would care to look at in your first class is your initList method and the delete item code.